# JButton size and JScrollPane not working well together

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jbutton

I am thoroughly confused. I have a pretty decent understanding of how each layout manger works and what each one is used for, but I'm not understanding what combination of layout managers and JPanels are necessary to make what I need work.

**What I am trying to accomplish**

I have a top bar, and a bottom bar of a container panel NORTH and SOUTH of a `BorderLayout`.
Within the Center panel, I want an unknown number of buttons 1 or more. Regardless of how many buttons there are they all need to be the same size, if there are dozens then scrolling should start happening once the buttons pass the window size limit.

**What I am getting**

Depending on the combination of layout mangers and how many nested JPanels I use and all sorts of trouble shooting, I get one massive button filling the entire CENTER element. I get 2 buttons that are the right size, but spread way apart (gap filling the CENTER space), or I get a dozen buttons that are the right size with no scroll.

I can solve any one of these, but then the other breaks. IE if I get a bunch of correctly sized buttons that properly scroll, then when I replace them with a single button its one massive button. Or if I get a single properly sized button then the larger quantity won't scroll etc.

**My Code**

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.*;

public class TestCode extends JFrame {
     private final JFrame frame;

    public TestCode(){

        frame = new JFrame();

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Test Title");

        JPanel windowContainer = new JPanel();      
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();             
        final JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();    
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();          

        JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");
        JButton browseButton = new JButton("Browse...");
        JButton testButton = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        final JTextField searchBar = new JTextField("Search database...");

        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));
        topPanel.add(title);
                title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        topPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), 100));
                // This is a subset of the top section. Top part is two panels, bottom panel is two cells (grid)
                JPanel topPanelSearch = new JPanel();
                topPanelSearch.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
                topPanelSearch.add(searchBar);
                topPanelSearch.add(searchButton);
        topPanel.add(topPanelSearch);

// PROBLEM AREA STARTS

//      middlePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        middlePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
//      middlePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(middlePanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        JPanel innerContainer = new JPanel();

        innerContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(innerContainer, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
//      innerContainer.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
//      innerContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            JButton button = new JButton("Button ");
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
            JPanel test = new JPanel();
            test.add(button);
            innerContainer.add(test);
        }

        JScrollPane midScroll = new JScrollPane(innerContainer);
        middlePanel.add(midScroll);

// PROBLEM AREA ENDS

        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        bottomPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), 100));
        bottomPanel.add(testButton);
        bottomPanel.add(browseButton);
        bottomPanel.add(exitButton);

        windowContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        windowContainer.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        windowContainer.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        windowContainer.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(windowContainer);


        frame.setTitle("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(480, 800);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestCode test = new TestCode();
    }
}
```

**Visual of some of the fail results**

I want the leftmost picture, but buttons should be stacked neatly (like the middle picture) when there are only a few results, and scrollable when there are lots.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: have you tried to add a new JPanel to the CENTER element and set its layout to gridlayout? If you make it with 0 lines and 1 column that should do the trick for any number of buttons (I haven't tested it) After that you just need to add the scroll...

Comment: @MyNameIsRui Yep, middlePanel in the code above is the panel that goes in CENTER and one of the many layout lines commented out is the grid layout that does just that. That is the result that I got on the left. Grid wasn't too friendly.

Comment: I see... I think you should try other layouts, maybe gridbaglayout or flowlayout (defining the number of components 1 per line) I haven't worked with swing for a while so I'm not even sure if such thing is possible. I hope you can fix it, I was really sure gridlayout would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try with `GridBagLayout` and a filler component that takes the remaining vertical space and therefore forces the buttons upwards.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.Box.Filler;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridbagButtons extends JFrame {

    private final JScrollPane jscrpButtons;
    private final JPanel jpButtons;

    public GridbagButtons() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());        

        jpButtons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        jscrpButtons = new JScrollPane(jpButtons);
        add(jscrpButtons, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // add a custom number of buttons
        int numButtons = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {
            JButton jbButton = new JButton("Button");
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = i;
            jpButtons.add(jbButton, gbc);
        }

        // add a vertical filler as last component to "push" the buttons up
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        Filler verticalFiller = new Filler(
                new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0), 
                new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0), 
                new java.awt.Dimension(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = numButtons;
        gbc.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        jpButtons.add(verticalFiller, gbc);

        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GridbagButtons().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

}
```